# Does IntelliJ not recognize protobuf in a Scala project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf file `src/main/protobuf/datamodel.proto` on my scala project. I was generating the java file using the `protoc` compiler installed on my ubuntu machine.

```
cd src/
protoc --java_out=main/java main/protobuf/datamodel.proto
```

datamodel.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package org.github.felipegutierrez.explore.akka.classic.remote.serialization;
option java_package = "org.github.felipegutierrez.explore.akka.classic.remote.serialization";
option java_outer_classname = "Datamodel";
message OnlineStoreUser {
  int32 userId = 1;
  string userName = 2;
  string userEmail = 4;
  string userPhone = 5;
}
message ProtobufVote {
  string ssn = 1;
  string candidate = 2;
}
```

So when I went to the `src` package `org.github.felipegutierrez.explore.akka.classic.remote.serialization` the corresponding file was there. Then I decided to use the [sbt-protobuf](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf) plugin. Basically I added on the `plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-protobuf" % "0.6.5")
```

and on the `build.sbt` file:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, ProtobufPlugin)
sourceDirectories in ProtobufConfig += (protobufExternalIncludePath in ProtobufConfig).value
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += (sourceDirectory in ProtobufConfig).value
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "com.google.protobuf" % "protobuf-java"  % "3.14.0",
  "com.google.protobuf" % "protoc" % "3.14.0" pomOnly(),
)
```

When I run `sbt protobuf:protobufGenerate` on the root of the project, the corresponding java files are created. That is fine, I can compile, use the `sbt docker:stage`, `sbt docker:publishLocal` without problems.

**ERROR**: But when I click on my IntelliJ IDEA `Build` > `Rebuild project` I am getting the error:

```
Datamodel is already defined as class Datamodel
public final class Datamodel {
```

I suppose that it has something to do with IntelliJ + sbt + protobuf configuration. When I search for classes `Datamodel` inside IntelliJ I find only one under the target directory `src_managed`, which is where the `sbt protobuf:protobufGenerate` generated it.

Does anyone have an idea where I can configure it correctly and make IntelliJ recognize the class as only one in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding this line on the `build.sbt`:

```
javaSource in ProtobufConfig := ((sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "generated")
```

and removing the `option java_package` line from the `datamodel.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package org.github.felipegutierrez.explore.akka.classic.remote.serialization;
option java_outer_classname = "Datamodel";
// commented this line because we are using "sbt-protobuf" plugin to generate java file on the specific location
// option java_package = "org.github.felipegutierrez.explore.akka.classic.remote.serialization";
message OnlineStoreUser {
  int32 userId = 1;
  string userName = 2;
  string userEmail = 4;
  string userPhone = 5;
}
```

now the command `sbt protobuf:protobufGenerate` generates one source file and IntelliJ see only one source file as well.